# Cancel a cron job that runs the script when there is an error in the same script

Tags: shell-script, cron

I have a script running every 5 minutes by cron. In the script itself, I want to add that if I encouter XYZ error, stop the cron job permanently and exit the script. Currently if I just put an `exit 1` in the script, when the error occurs, the cron will restart the script and the loop continues.

Comment: The simplest option is probably to create a particular file in `/tmp` when the error occurs (before `exit 1`), and check at the beginning of the script if this file exists - if yes, exit immediately. This way the cron will actually restart the script, but the script will exit immediately doing nothing.

Comment: @raj  Building on that, putting a diagnostic into that file would be helpful: the file creation date shows when the event occurred.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, cron jobs don't support this use case. You have already received good responses providing workarounds. However, this is reasonably easy in other task scheduler/service managers such as systemd. For example, for non-root users, create a directory in `~/.config/systemd/user` with a service and a timer:

mytask.service

```
[Unit]
Description=My Task
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStopPost=/bin/sh -c 'if [ "$$EXIT_STATUS" = 1 ]; then systemctl --user stop mytask.timer; fi'
ExecStart=/bin/myscript.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

mytask.timer

```
[Unit]
Description=Run script every 60 seconds

[Timer]
Persistent=true
OnBootSec=120
OnUnitActiveSec=60 # run every 60 seconds
Unit=mytask.service

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

Finally, start your service and timer:

```
systemctl --user enable mytask.service
systemctl --user enable mytask.timer
systemctl --user start mytask.timer
systemctl --user start mytask.service
```

If you script fails (with exit code = 1), your service will disable the timer and the script won't run again.

Answer (score 1):

*"Cancel a cron job"* is where you made a conceptual mistake. You can cancel a process, that is, only one occurrence of a cron job. If you want your cron job not to be executed anymore, say *"Disable a cron job"*

Unfortunately, there is only one way to *"disable a cron job"*: by editing crontabs. `cron` does never write back on its own crontabs considered read-only.

So you want your job to *"disable himself"*. The way to do that is to manage a dedicated status file, and install a door in your script.

Example: if `yourtask` returns nonzero status, touch an error flag that stops further execution:

```
@hourly [ -f yourtask_error ] || yourtask || touch yourtask_error
```

However, it hurts the principles and makes a cron job that is not really a cron job, anymore.

Comment: I actually want to disable the cron job if the script fails.

Comment: ok, I've shown [ -f yourtask_error ] || task_exit_1 || touch yourtask_error

Comment: It would be silly to automatically edit crontab according to feedback, and it should be coded in the cron job itself. Awful.